# How do I derive a time-dependent velocity vector field and position vector field?

Tags: vectors, vector-fields, chain-rule, fluid-dynamics

The velocity vector field can be described as follows:

$$\vec{V} = u(x,y,z,t)\hat{i} + v(x,y,z,t)\hat{j} + w(x,y,z,t)\hat{k}$$

What I understand from this is that for **ALL** particles at some random arbitrary location $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ and some random arbitrary time $(t_0)$, we have

$$\vec{V_0} = u(x_0,y_0,z_0,t_0)\hat{i} + v(x_0,y_0,z_0,t_0)\hat{j} + w(x_0,y_0,z_0,t_0)\hat{k}$$

This makes sense to me!

However, I start to think about the position function. Recall that we are also using Eulerian frame.

For example, say we have a position vector for particle **A**

$$\vec{r_A}=x(t)\hat{i} + y(t)\hat{j} + z(t)\hat{k}$$

taken with respect to the origin of our Cartesian coordinate frame.

Meaning that

$$\vec{r_A}=\vec{r_A}(x(t), y(t), z(t))=\vec{r_A}(t)$$

It also follow that, to get the velocity vector for particle **A**,

$$\frac{d\vec{r_A}}{dt} = \vec{V_A}=\vec{V_A}(t)$$

**QUESTION:** How does one go about, mathematically, of describing a position vector field for **ALL** particles?

Thinking about it further, it would make sense to describe the position vector field for **ALL** particles as

$$\vec{r}=x\hat{i} + y\hat{j} + z\hat{k}$$

since the position of **ALL** particles is, *well*, its position. My guess is that this would not be a function of time since we are only looking at that location. Much like $\vec{V}$, we are only describing a certain location at a certain time. However, the location we are looking at is the position

However, to get the velocity vector field, we have to differentiate position,

$$\frac{d\vec{r}(x, y, z)}{dt} = \vec{V}(x,y,z,t)$$

Here is where I get stuck again...

**QUESTION:** If my assumption is correct, what would the chain rule look like for this equation?

**QUESTION:** If the velocity field for **ALL** particles is a function of position and time, $\vec{V}=\vec{V}(x,y,z,t)$, would that mean that the position is also a function of time? How can that be?

**Thank you!** Feel free to suggest reading material that can also help! I am very curious!

Comment: Hi there, I'm not sure I understand the question completely but I think you may be looking for the material derivative, have you heard of it? Also I think your initial velocity field may be missing the actual function name for the z component